Visual duplication bug with Java apps
I've come to ask for help here because I haven't found a solution to my problem anywhere, not even a hint or a mention.
My problem is as follows:
I need to develop an application in Java. Up to now, everything was going well, but when I wanted to add a JColorChooser, I now have a visual duplication bug that prevents me from using my application correctly.
When I move the mouse over certain elements (notably radio buttons and the like), part of the interface is duplicated and hides the contents of my window. Moreover, the duplication goes away when I resize the window, but comes back as soon as I put my mouse back in the wrong place.
The duplication in the JColorChooser
The first thing I did was to find out what was causing the problem. I started using a Java application and found the same bug.
I then tried uninstalling Java, my IDE (Eclipse), reinstalling everything, restarting the computer but nothing helped: still the same bug.
Then I searched the Internet but couldn't find anything.
That's why I've come to ask for your help. Do you know of such a bug? Would you have any clues as to how to solve it?
Thank you in advance for your reply.
...........................
